# what does kubernetes use the container pause-amd64 for?

Tags: kubernetes

I set up the `kubernetes` cluster, and I found the `pause-amd64:3.0` container on master or minion like this:

```
[root@k8s-minion1 kubernetes]# docker ps |grep pause
c3026adee957        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0           "/pause"                 22 minutes ago      Up 22 minutes                           k8s_POD.d8dbe16c_redis-master-343230949-04glm_default_ce3f60a9-095d-11e7-914b-0a77ecd65f3e_66c108d5
202df18d636e        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0           "/pause"                 24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                             k8s_POD.d8dbe16c_kube-proxy-js0z0_kube-system_2866cfc2-0891-11e7-914b-0a77ecd65f3e_c8e1a667
072d3414d33a        gcr.io/google_containers/pause-amd64:3.0           "/pause"                 24 hours ago        Up 24 hours                             k8s_POD.d8dbe16c_kube-flannel-ds-tsps5_default_2866e3fb-0891-11e7-914b-0a77ecd65f3e_be4b719e
[root@k8s-minion1 kubernetes]#
```

so what does `k8s` use this for ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's part of the infrastructure. This container is started first in all Pods to setup the network for the Pod.

It does nothing after the Pod has started.

Here is the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/build/pause).